# VB.NET Auto Implemented Property Missing in Reflection

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have a class with two public properties, one has a getter defined and the other is an auto implemented property (which creates a getter/setter internally)

```
Public ReadOnly Property PendingAdd As String 
  Get
    Return m_pendingadd
  End Get
End Property

'Auto Implemented Property
Public AuditorName As String
```

When using reflection and calling GetProperties(), I only get the property with the `Get` defined, the auto implemented property does not get returned.  **How can I get both properties using reflection?**

```
Dim lobjSiteType As Type = Me.GetType()
For Each pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In lobjSiteType.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
   'Do stuff
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Public AuditorName As String` is not a `property` it's a class variable.

This is an auto property in VB.NET:

```
Property YourProperty As String
```

Comment: I should have caught that one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A property is considered public to reflection if it has at least one accessor that is public. Otherwise the property is considered private, and you must use BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static (in Visual Basic, combine the values using Or) to get it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: See @T McKeown's answer - your variable isn't a property